# USB not recognized on windws after file transfer on ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, usb, usb-drive

Anytime I use ANY USB storage device on my Ubuntu machine, it's somehow corrupted on my Windows machine.

Filesystems Effected: NTFS, FAT32
Ubuntu Version: 16.04
Windows Version: 8.1 Pro

Steps to reproduce:

1. copy files to or from usb while connected to Ubuntu machine.
2. Use the unmount button in files.
3. Remove from USB
4. Plug into Windows device (not recognized or requires repair)

There are no error messages or anything like that from the Ubuntu side of things. What can I do to debug this problem?

Comment: What file system is there in the USB drive? Which version of Ubuntu are you running? What happens if you unmount the partition in the USB drive with a command line: `sudo umount /dev/sdxn`where x is the drive letter and n is the partition number?

Comment: The file system seems to be irrelevant. It happens to both NTFS and FAT32. Ubuntu 16.04 (tagged). I will try that command when I'm back at that computer, and update my answer.

Comment: This *should* not happen. It works for me in similar situations, with FAT32, NTFS, Ubuntu 16.04 (installed and up to date) and Windows 8.1 (up to date). I guess you have tried to copy a file in Windows, unplug from Windows and plug back in (without plugging into the Ubuntu computer). It seems to me that the buffers are not completely flushed (written to the drive). Unmounting *should* run `sync` and flush the buffers before finishing its task. Have you tried with a live Ubuntu system (booted from a USB drive) in the Ubuntu computer and in the Windows computer?

Comment: Maybe you are removing it while it still does sync or unmounting. Try to call `sync` and then `sudo umount /dev/xxxx` from console instead point 2.

Comment: Thanks all. I don't have access to my windows machine right now. I will try your suggestions later this evening.